# How to know standard objects in netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

How to know what are standard objects/records in net suite?

i want to know how to find the difference between standard and custom objects/records.

Thanks,
Rvn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here are two ways to check if a record is either a Standard or Custom record:

1. Check the Custom records listing

   *Customization* **>** *Lists, Records, & Fields* **>** *Record Types*
2. Check the URL of the record

   If the URL has *custrecordentry.nl* in the latter portions, then it is a Custom record.

   i.e.  https://system.netsuite.com/app/common/custom/**custrecordentry.nl**?rectype=1&id=1

Answer (score 1):

Check Netsuite record browser
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_2/schema/record/account.html

Comment: This URL changes regularly with the Netsuite version.  Currently it's https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_2/schema/record/account.html

Answer (score 0):

Aside from checking the record browser, if you are not familiar with the account check if the record was renamed from the standard one:

Setup > Company > Rename Records/Transactions

Depending on the implementation a company may rename a standard record to a different name that would fit to their use. So a standard record called "Project" may be renamed to "Numbers", this is a common scenario and may be a pitfall for you to think that you are dealing with a custom record.